# SSRS with VS 2012 agregation in calculated field

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2008

[image]I'm working with SSRS 2008 and Visual Vtudio 2012.

A calculated field in SSRS has a limitation; that is that we cant use an aggregation function inside it.

For example:

```
=IIf(Fields!Year.Value = Previous(Fields!Year.Value),0,Fields!Sum_Alpha_Positive.Value)
```

What is the best work around that can be done to solve that issue?

Comment: Can you add some sample data (a few rows for example), your expected results and why you can't achieve this against the sample data? Please keep things as simple as possible. In your example the only aggregate expression is the `Previous` expression, there is nothing stopping it from working.

Comment: when adding a Previous expression in a calculated field on the Data set , it stop working giving the error above

Comment: OK, thanks, got it now. Is there any reason why you can't just add that expression as an extra field when you're actually displaying the data? An idea of what you're achieve would be helpful.